# Why to store username and password in Keychain in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

I have worked with `NSUserDefault` but this keychain concept is totally new for me.

I have tried looking for similar Questions but couldn't find the exact reason to do so.

**What I have done:**

I already know how to store data in `NSUserDefault`. and also the reason why do we need to store it.

**Regarding Keychain** I just know that storing in keychain stores the data with some extra security by encoding the original text while `NSUserDefault` stores the data as plain text. And it also stores the data even after the application is removed.

Is this the only reason for storing the data in keychain?

**Edit:**
I got [this link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html) which says exactly what I have said.

Comment: That's kind of a huge reason. If my bank stored my personal info in plaintext, I'd change banks. Same with my apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain data is more secure in comparision of NSUserDefault. and keychain data also in device after remove application from device. For more about keychain wrapper read [this.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Answer (score 0):

maybe [LKKeychain](https://github.com/lakesoft/LKKeychain) could help:

> LKKeychain class is a tiny keychain services wrapper. It provides:
>
> Add account Update account Delete account Dump accounts (for debug)